# I want to be able to enable browser caching on my Godaddy Cpanel Apache Hosting Server and have the following code. but this code does not work

Tags: php

```
ExpiresActive On    
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000    
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000    
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000    
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000    
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000    
ExpiresByType text/css A86400    
ExpiresByType text/javascript A86400    
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2592000
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable browser caching you need to edit your HTTP headers to set expiry dates on certain types of files.
In this code we will set our caching parameters to tell the browser what types of files to cache.
please try following code.

```
 ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, this is work for me, now i am testing my site into the google speed test, sometimes it shows that you enable a browsing cache and any time google ask browsing cache you have to fix it..

Comment: @KuldeepSingh consider accepting the answer then in order to mark it as solved. Tick the checkmark till it turns green.